# Calculate the order of $[9]_{31}\in (\mathbb Z /31\mathbb Z )^*$ and say if the equation $x^3=9$ have solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I want to check if my solution is correct, what differ slightly of other solutions to this question in this site. I know that $(\mathbb Z /31\mathbb Z )^*\cong \mathbb Z /30\mathbb Z $ and so there exists some isomorphism $f$ between these cyclic groups, therefore

$$
[1]_{31}=[9^n]_{31}\iff 2n f([3]_{31})=[0]_{30}\iff \frac{2n f([3]_{31})}{30}\in \mathbb Z \\
\therefore\quad n\in\{1,3,5,15\}
$$
A direct computation show that $[9^k]_{31}\neq [1]_{31}$ for $k\in\{1,3,5\}$ so the order of $[9]_{31}$ must be $15$.

The second part of the exercise ask to show if there are solutions to the equation $x^3=9$ in $(\mathbb Z /31\mathbb Z )^*$. If this would be the case then we will have that $x^{45}=x^{30}\cdot x^{15}=9^{15}=1$ so the order of $x$ must be less or equal to $15$ but $(x^3)^5=9^5=1$ what cannot be possible as the order of $9$ is $15$.$\Box$